# VBS WScript fails to execute

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, wsh

I am having issues getting the Run (or Exec) methods to work with VBS.  I have been having so much difficulty getting an arbitrary command to run that I have resorted to putting my command in a batch file and trying to use Run to just call the .bat file.  Even this method isn't working.  Code is as follows:

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run "C:\Path\to\my\batch.bat"
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Opening a command prompt and simply entering 'C:\Path\to\my\batch.bat' runs exactly as I would expect it to.  However when using the VBS code above, it does nothing at all.  The command in the batch file is straight forward consisting of the path to the executable and then a path to a file for the executable to act on.  Changing the Run command above as follows results in the same thing as trying to call the batch file - nothing at all.

```
objShell.Run "C:\Path\to\my\executable.exe C:\Path\to\my\file.extension"
```

My ultimate goal would be to build the path to file string within the script, but that seems irrelevant when even hardcoding it fails.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If executable path in batch.bat a full path?

Comment: You may be missing quotes. Example: `objShell.Run """c:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe"" ""c:\Users\Public\desktop.ini"""`

Comment: My batch file is using the full path to the exe (and the full path to the file).

Comment: Also, adding in the extra quotes does not have any impact.  It's been suggested to my by a colleague that the issue might have to do with running 32-bit executables on a 64-bit machine, but he didn't have any more details on that.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the batch file? I successfully ran your VBS using my own test batch file.

Comment: The command in the second code block in the OP (i.e. the part between the quotes) is the contents of the batch file.

Comment: So, `C:\Path\to\my\executable.exe C:\Path\to\my\file.extension` is the complete contents of your batch file?

Comment: What if you try to run notepad? `objShell.Run "notepad"`?

Comment: Tried `Result = objShell.Run("C:\Path\to\my\batch.bat",1,True)` then `Wscript.Echo Result`? Have a read at [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx). Did you also tried `Wscript.Echo "Err(" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description"` to get a hint?

Comment: You may also have an issue if that executable requires Admin privilege while you execute this vbs in non-administrator shell - Windows UAC may have blocked it?

Comment: You say that calling the `Run` method doesn't do anything at all, but how did you verify that? What are the expected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with two changes.  First, I added "cmd /c" to the front of my command.

This resulted in getting a different error (file not found) and it was actually being caused by timing issues with the program I was trying to execute.  Adding a 1 second delay after the Run command (before disposing the objSehll object) resolved this issue.

Thanks to everyone who responded.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
objShell.Exec "C:\Path\to\my\batch.bat"
```

Or

```
objShell.Run "%comspec% /K C:\Path\to\my\batch.bat"
```